# Throw exception when search result found

Tags: java, search, recursion

I've recently read in BS's c++ book, that it is ok to throw the result of a recursive search to immediately return from the whole call stack at once.
Is it ok to do the same in java? I know it is possible, but is it discouraged and considered a to have a bad smell? 
It is easier than using a 'found' flag and checking it every time.

Comment: Why the vote to close? This is a fair question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely would go for a flag. Sure you can do it with `Exception` but it is not meant to control code flux with exceptions. Exceptions are not free in cost, while a simple check of the flag would cost O(1).

Answer (score 2):

A flag would indeed be a better option.

Exceptions should be used for just that, handling unexpected behavior, and not to control the workflow of your program. Keep in mind that throwing an exception will make all the calling methods handle it explicitly, and that will make your code *alot* more coupled than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use a flag.  Exceptions are designed to be used in *exceptional conditions*.  They aren't supposed to be return codes.  Furthermore, throwing exceptions incurs a rather significant cost while checking a flag is a very quick operation.